# Laravel - Error "Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given"

Tags: laravel, validation

What's wrong with this code ?

```
class DeleteDetail extends FormRequest {

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        $request = Request::all();
        $rules = [
            'hobby' => [
                'string',
                'between:3,20',
                Rule::exists('user_hobby')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->where('hobby', $request['hobby'])->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
                }),
            ],
        ];

        return Validator::make($request, $rules);
    }

}
```

**Error that I'm getting :**

Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given

Comment: Are you trying to create Request Validation class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are returning the wrong value from inside the `rules` method itself, you should return the `array containing your validation rules` instead of `Validation::make`:

```
public function rules() {
    ...

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `rules` function should return the array with the rules.

```
public function rules() {
    $request = Request::all();
    $rules = [
        'hobby' => [
                'string',
                'between:3,20',
                Rule::exists('user_hobby')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->where('hobby', $request['hobby'])->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
                }),
            ],
        ];

    return $rules;
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function store(DeleteDetail $request) 
{
   // the code in here has passed the validation..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.